# How to select a fixed dimension ROI in ENVI?

Tags: raster, remote-sensing, imagery, envi

ENVI provides the freedom to select ROIs by drawing polygons etc. I want to clip a fixed size ROI, say 512 x 512 in size. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ENVI does not provide an option for fixed size ROI. One possible way to do that is by creating polygon shapefile and draw polygons with fixed length and width using ArcGIS, then import the polygon shapefile from ENVI as ROI.